# Hide input on submit (VUE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, vue.js

Im working on a Vue app - very simple said a todo list, like the following example. However i would like to hide my input field on submit (and hereby only show the output as it already does), so i can make a nice transition, since only one item should be added per input field.

Hope someone can help me with a good solution!

https://jsfiddle.net/541rd96r/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#madplan",
  data: {
    newTask_mandag: "",
    taskList_mandag: [],
  },

  methods: {
    addTask_mandag: function() {
      var task = this.newTask_mandag.trim();
      if (task) {
        this.taskList_mandag.push({
          text: task
        });
        this.newTask_mandag = "";
      }
    },

    removeSubTask_mandag: function(task) {
      var index = this.taskList_mandag.indexOf(task);
      this.taskList_mandag.splice(index, 1);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="madplan">
  <section>
    <section class="prefetch" class="panel">
      <input class="input typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Tilføj ret til madplanen" v-model="newTask_mandag " v-on:keyup.enter="addTask_mandag">
    </section>

    <details v-for="task in taskList_mandag" v-bind:key="task.text" class="sub-list-item">
      <summary>{{ task.text }} <button v-on:click="removeSubTask_mandag(task)">X</button></summary>

    </details>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad snipping formation, it's copy paste!

Comment: You should format your code to be readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the `input` tag add the directive `v-if='showInput'` to show the element conditionally. Then add the computed property to determine the condition like so

```
   computed: {
        showInput: function() {
        return !this.taskList_mandag.length
      }
    },
```

Comment: Ah thanks alot, this was just what i was looking for! It works in the jsfiddle, but not im my local script - yet. I will get it fixed though.

Comment: You are welcome. Hope you get the local script working as well

Comment: I did, it had some trouble with my twitter-typeahead on the input. 

I have another question for you, i will post it as a comment tomorrow - unless you got other preferences for how i should do it :)

Comment: A comment would be alright if that question is related to this one

Comment: Hey again, i posted a new question instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542883/post-to-list-from-vue-component

Comment: Hey @CarstenAndersen. I've posted an answer for you on that other question. I hope you find it helpfull

Comment: Thanks alot, im testing it out!