# Post to list from Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How can i post through subInput(in component, 2nd input) to the list outside the component? I can see that the input posts to subTaskList, but wont post it to the list?

For clarifications: I'm trying to make a food planner, where the main inputs with placeholder="Tilføj ret til madplanen" to be the food for the day, and the second input with placeholder="Tilføj til indkøbsseddel" to add to a shoppinglist (#list)

(sorry for the danish placeholders)

```js
      Vue.component('list-component', {
            data: function() {
                return {
                    newTask: "",
                    taskList: [],
                    newSubTask: "",
                    subTaskList: [],
                };
            },
            template:
                '<div>' +

                '<section class="prefetch" class="panel">' +
                '<input  v-if="showInput" class="input typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Tilføj ret til madplanen" v-model="newTask" v-on:keyup.enter="addTask">' +
                '</section>' +

                '<details v-for="task in taskList" v-bind:key="task.text" class="sub-list-item">' +
                '<summary>{{ task.text }}<button v-on:click="removeSubTask(task)">X</button>' + '</summary>' +
                '<input class="subInput" type="text" placeholder="Tilføj til indkøbsseddel" v-model="newSubTask" v-on:keyup.enter="addSubTask">' +
                '</details>' +

                '</div>',

            computed: {
                showInput: function() {
                    return !this.taskList.length
                },
            },

            methods: {
                //addTasks
                //
                addTask: function() {
                    var task = this.newTask.trim();
                    if (task) {
                        this.taskList.push({
                            text: task
                        });
                        this.newTask = "";
                    }
                },

                addSubTask: function() {
                    var task = this.newSubTask.trim();
                    if (task) {
                        this.subTaskList.push({
                            text: task
                        });
                        this.newSubTask = "";
                    }
                },

                //removeTasks
                //
                removeSubTask: function(task) {
                    var index = this.taskList.indexOf(task);
                    this.taskList.splice(index, 1);
                    var index = this.subTaskList.indexOf(task);
                    this.subTaskList.splice(index, 999);
                },
            },
        });


        new Vue({
            el: "#madplan",
            data: {
                newTask: "",
                taskList: [],
                newSubTask: "",
                subTaskList: [],
            },
        });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <section id="madplan" class="section-wrapper">

        <section class="check-list">
            <h1>Mandag</h1>
            <list-component></list-component>
            <h1>Tirsdag</h1>
            <list-component></list-component>

        </section>
        <ul id="list">
            <h2>list</h2>
            <li v-for="task in subTaskList" v-bind:key="task.text" class="list-item">{{ task.text }}</li>
        </ul>

    </section>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txh85nq0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish communication between Vue.js components, you need to leverage the [Custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events)

For your components to work as intended you need to make a few modifications.

First correct this line

```
<section class="prefetch" class="panel">
```

to remove duplicate class definition. You should use

```
<section class="prefetch panel">
```

Then in the method `addTask` in `list-component` declaration add the line

```
this.$emit('addedtask', task);
```

right after

```
this.newTask = "";
```

While at it, why not also add this

```
this.$emit('removedtask', task);
```

right after the line

```
this.subTaskList.splice(index, 999);
```

in the method `removeSubTask` on the same `list-component` declaration
Now catch the events emitted in the child component update `#madplan` template by changing

```
<list-component></list-component>
```

to this

```
<list-component 
  v-on:addedtask='acknowledgeAddedTask'
  v-on:removedtask='acknowledgeRemovedTask'
    ></list-component>
```

You will also need to declare the two new methods so that `#madplan` now includes

```
methods: {
  acknowledgeAddedTask: function(task) {
    this.$data.subTaskList.push({ text: task })
  },
  acknowledgeRemovedTask: function(task) {
    this.$data.subTaskList = this.$data.subTaskList.filter(it => it.text != task.text)
    }
 }
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txh85nq0/2/)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. This isnt completely the result i was thinking about, but i understand the confusion - and appreciate your support!
The new fiddle adds the input from the input field in the .panel section to the list, however the needed was that the second input (the one with the subInput class) to add to the list.

Comment: Nevermind, seemed to fix this myself by adding the
 "this.$emit('addedtask', task)" to addSubTask instead!

Comment: I have another simple question. 
I added the line "this.subTaskList.splice(index, 999);" to the removeSubTask function, because i wanted it to remove the items from the list, which were added by that input field. This doesnt work, atleast not all of the time. And when it does, it only removes one, not all.

Comment: To remove an element from an array, filtering the array to find the element to remove excludes it from the returned list. Try changing `removeSubTask: function(task) {
                    var index = this.taskList.indexOf(task);
                    this.taskList.splice(index, 1);
                    var index = this.subTaskList.indexOf(task);
                    this.subTaskList.splice(index, 999);
                },` to  `removeSubTask: function(task) {
    this.$data.subTaskList = this.$data.subTaskList.filter(it => it.text != task.text)
    }`

Comment: I have alot to learn. Again, thanks alot for the support. It helped me alot! Im still a rookie on the js side :)

Comment: This is so embarrasing, but you have been a great help so far.
If you got the time and feeling for it, you can take a look at this aswell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549998/vue-v-model-with-css-styling

Comment: Don't worry about it. Most of what I know about web development I learnt here. I'll do my best to help.