# Vue v-model with css styling?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, styling

It is hard to explain this problem, so i think i will start by showing what i have:

```js
        Vue.component('list-component', {
            data: function() {
                return {
                    newTask: "",
                    taskList: [],
                    newSubTask: "",
                    subTaskList: [],
                };
            },
            template:
                '<div>' +

                '<section class="prefetch">' +
                '<input  v-if="showInput" class="input typeahead" type="text" placeholder="mainInput" v-model="newTask" v-on:keyup.enter="addTask">' +
                '</section>' +

                '<details v-for="task in taskList" v-bind:key="task.text" class="sub-list-item">' +
                '<summary>{{ task.text }}<button v-on:click="removeTask(task)">X</button>' + '</summary>' +
                '<input class="subInput" type="text" placeholder="subInput" v-model="newSubTask" v-on:keyup.enter="addSubTask">' +
                '</details>' +

                '</div>',

            computed: {
                showInput: function() {
                    return !this.taskList.length
                },
            },

            methods: {
                //addTasks
                //
                addTask: function() {
                    var task = this.newTask.trim();
                    if (task) {
                        this.taskList.push({
                            text: task
                        });
                        this.newTask = "";
                    }
                },

                addSubTask: function() {
                    var task = this.newSubTask.trim();
                    if (task) {
                        this.subTaskList.push({
                            text: task
                        });
                        this.newSubTask = "";
                        this.$emit('addedtask', task);

                    }
                },

                //removeTasks
                //
                removeTask: function(task) {
                    var index = this.taskList.indexOf(task);
                    this.taskList.splice(index, 1);
                    this.$emit('removedtask', task);
                },
            },
        });


        new Vue({
            el: "#madplan",
            data: {
                newTask: "",
                taskList: [],
                newSubTask: "",
                subTaskList: [],
            },
            methods: {
              acknowledgeAddedTask: function(task) {
                this.$data.subTaskList.push({ text: task })
              },
              acknowledgeRemovedTask: function(task) {
                this.$data.subTaskList = this.$data.subTaskList.filter(it => it.text != task.text)
              },
              removeSubTask: function(task) {
                  var index = this.subTaskList.indexOf(task);
                  this.subTaskList.splice(index, 1);
                  this.$emit('removedtask', task);
              },
            }
        });
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <section id="madplan" class="section-wrapper">

        <section class="check-list">

            <list-component
              class='first'
              v-on:addedtask='acknowledgeAddedTask'
              v-on:removedtask='acknowledgeRemovedTask'
            ></list-component>

            <list-component
              class='second'   
              v-on:addedtask='acknowledgeAddedTask'
              v-on:removedtask='acknowledgeRemovedTask'
            ></list-component>
            
                    </section>
        <ul id="indkøbseddel">
            <h2>Indkøbsseddel</h2>
            <li v-for="task in subTaskList" v-bind:key="task.text" class="list-item">{{ task.text }}<button v-on:click="removeSubTask(task)">X</button></li>
        </ul>

    </section>
```

So, if you try to run through the app, and add some text to the mainInput field, with the class .first - this new details get the class .first aswell. But when you open the details and make an input into the new field (subInput), it posts this input to the li in ul id="indkøbseddel" - but now the class / styling is gone.

Can i somehow transfer this to the li?
What i am trying to accomplish is different colors on the li, wether it has been added from the first input (list-component) or the second.

Hard to explain, so feel free to ask questions. It doesnt have to be done this way, i just need to be able to differentiate between the li's added depending on which input field.

Thanks in advance!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucL2pv6f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty in passing the class of the `component` to its `parent` becomes easier to approach once you realize that the expression `v-on:addedtask='acknowledgeAddedTask'` is equivalent to `v-on:addedtask='task => acknowledgeAddedTask(task)'`

You can then build upon this to change your component declaration such that `class='first' v-on:addedtask='acknowledgeAddedTask` becomes `class='first' v-on:addedtask='task => acknowledgeAddedTask("first", task)'` and like wise for the second component.

Then you need to change to `acknowledgeAddedTask` method to accommodate the new parameter so that you end up with

```
acknowledgeAddedTask: function(cls, task) { 
  this.$data.subTaskList.push({ 
    text: task, 
    class: "list-item " + cls 
  })
}
```

Finally, on the `li`s of `#madplan` change the class attribute to `:class=task.class` so that each list item has the right class as set while adding that item.

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucL2pv6f/1/)

Comment: I have some more free reputation for you, on my newest question related to the same Vue app, about LocalStorage :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587976/localstorage-in-vue-app-with-multiple-inputs

Comment: I have a relevant question for the same topic, because i dont think i understood your above answer correctly. Look at this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucL2pv6f/3/, i've added a label under the input field (as an animatable placeholder), however i cant seem to figure out how to add some styling(for animation) to  the label with the input field is in focus. 
I did this already with jQuery, however this animates ALL the labels when ONE input is focused!

Hope you will see this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is bind each sub-task li so it has a class of .first or .second based on which parent task created it. Check out the [class and style binding section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) in the Vue docs.